# How to query with comparison operator using symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I can currently do this

```
Enrollment.where('starts_at < ?', Time.current)
```

Since I can do this

```
Enrollment.where(starts_at: Time.current)
```

Is there a way to use the same format for comparison operators? I thought one of these would work but they don't

```
Enrollment.where(starts_at: "< #{Time.current}")
```

or

```
Enrollment.where('starts_at <': Time.current)
```

It would be really great to be able to do something like this

```
Enrollment.where(state: :active, 'starts_at <': Time.current)
```

Comment: You can't use `Enrollment.where('starts_at < ? AND state = ?', Time.current, 'active')` (or the number if active is an integer)?

Comment: Yes, I can. I was just wondering (for fun) if it was possible to use the "newer" format with symbols. This query seems to work `Enrollment.where(state: :active, starts_at: ..Time.current)`

Comment: The Sequel has something like this `Enrollment.where{starts_at < Time.current}` https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel%2FDataset:where

Answer (score 5):

Rails does not have a built in way* to create less than/greater than conditions with the hash syntax. You can use endless ranges to create greater than or equal:

```
adults = Citizen.where(age: 18..)
```

And beginning with [Rails 6.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36696) you can use beginless ranges to create less than or equal:

```
minors = Citizen.where(age: ..17)
```

However its actually pretty simple to create the desired query if you need LT and not LTE:

```
Enrollment.where(state: :active)
          .where('starts_at < ?', Time.current)
```

You can also use Arel:

```
Enrollment.where(state: :active).where(
  Enrollment.arel_table[:starts_at].lt(Time.current)
)
```

* at the time of writing, see @Yakov's answer for the proposed feature

Answer (score 5):

This feature might be available in Rails 6.1.

```
Enrollment.where('starts_at <': Time.current)
```

It's still discussing:

- [The feature PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39613)
- [Revert of the feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39862)
- [Revert of the feature revert, still open](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39863)

Comment: Good find. Although the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-mixed-hash-syntaxes) recommends that you stick to the hash rocket syntax when the keys are not symbols - using `'starts_at <':` will implicitly cast to a symbol and gives me eye twitches.

Comment: Yeah, it just how it present in the question and in those PRs.